# React JS, Variable name is not saved when fetching data from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The issue I got is that the fetched Data from API is not saved to a variable. Please look at the `fearvalue`, it's being called later and the value of that is an empty string.

APY component

```
export let fearvalue = [];

export const fearAndGreed = () => {
    // 1. Create a new XMLHttpRequest object   
    let bitcoinAPY = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // 2. Configure it: GET-request for the URL /article/.../load    
    bitcoinAPY.open("GET", "https://api.alternative.me/fng/?limit=10&date_format=us", false)    
    bitcoinAPY.onload = () => {    
        const data = JSON.parse(bitcoinAPY.response);    
        /*const saveStaticDataToFile = () => {    
          let blob = new Blob(['Welcome'],    
          {type: 'text/plain;charset=utf-8'});    
          saveStaticDataToFile(blob, "static.txt")    
        }*/    
        console.log(data)    
        fearvalue = data.data[0];    
    }
    // 3. Send the request over the network
    bitcoinAPY.send();
}

window.addEventListener('load', fearAndGreed)
```

`fearvalue` is being called in this component and it is a blank value. Can anyone help me with saving data to this variable?

import './App.css';

```
import './Apy_TAPI';
import './Bitcoin Fear&Greed';
import { DataFormatting } from './DataFormatting.js';
import { fearvalue } from './Bitcoin Fear&Greed';

    import './App.css';
import './Apy_TAPI';
import './Bitcoin Fear&Greed';
import { DataFormatting } from './DataFormatting.js';
import { fearvalue } from './Bitcoin Fear&Greed';

function App() {
  const test1 = "test1"
  console.log(fearvalue)

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <p>
          Bitcoin analyst tool
        </p>
      </header>
      <div className='Text'>
        <h1>
          <img className="Image" src="https://alternative.me/crypto/fear-and-greed-index.png" alt="Latest Crypto Fear & Greed Index" />
        </h1>
        <h2>
          https://bitinfocharts.com/pl/bitcoin/address/1P5ZEDWTKTFGxQjZphgWPQUpe554WKDfHQ <br />
          <br />
          {fearvalue} <br />
        </h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Exported values can be edited but they can't be overridden. Try `fearvalue.push(...data.data[0];)` instead of `fearvalue = data.data[0];`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the response in a proper way. in `React.js`, you could use `useState` to create a state variable and set the response in it.

First, you need to save the response in a state variable:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

export const fearAndGreed = () => {  
    const [fearValue, setFearValue] = useState() // initialize with proper value according to your data type, it could be a empty array [] or an object {}.

    let bitcoinAPY = new XMLHttpRequest();   
    bitcoinAPY.open("GET", "https://api.alternative.me/fng/?limit=10&date_format=us", false)    
    bitcoinAPY.onload = () => {    
        const data = JSON.parse(bitcoinAPY.response);    
        setFearValue(data.data[0])  // ------> set the fearValue here
    }
    bitcoinAPY.send();
}

window.addEventListener('load', fearAndGreed)
```

So far, the first part is done. but you need the `fearValue` in the other component. to achieve this, there are some solutions like using a `Global State Manager` like **Redux** or **ContextApi**. without them, your implementation would be tricky since you can't use the `lifting state up` technique because you didn't use `fearAndGreed` as a child component in the parent component (App).

In such cases, you can implement a custom hook with `fearAndGreed` function. since the function invokes once after the page loading, you can implement this by calling the API after your components did mount.

Let's make a custom hook with the current `fearAndGreed` function in this way:

```
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

export const useFearAndGreed = () => {
  const [fearValue, setFearValue] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    let bitcoinAPY = new XMLHttpRequest();   
    bitcoinAPY.open("GET", "https://api.alternative.me/fng/?limit=10&date_format=us", false)    
    bitcoinAPY.onload = () => {    
        const data = JSON.parse(bitcoinAPY.response);    
        setFearValue(data.data[0])  // ------> set the fearValue here
    }
    bitcoinAPY.send();
  }, [])

  return fearValue;
}
```

##### Explanation:

With a few changes, `fearAndGreed` function becomes a custom hook `useFearAndGreed`.
The API will call in the `useEffect` after the component did mount (with an empty array of dependencies).
The hook will return the `fearValue` on every change.

Now, time to use this custom hook inside of the App component:

```
function App() {
 const fearValue = useFearAndGreed()

  return (
    <div>
     {fearValue}
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

**Note:** I removed the other parts of implementation in the `App` component to simplify it. you should include your own implementation within.

Now, every time the `App` component did mount, the `useFearAndGreed` will be invoked and return the `fearValue` which can be saved in a constant `fearValue` to use in the `div` element.